# Unmarshalling leads to unexpected element message

Tags: xml, eclipse, xsd, jaxb, unmarshalling

currently, I am dealing with an error message, when trying to unmarshall from a test file. I am receiving the following error message:

- unexpected element (uri:"", local:"dataList"). Expected elements are (none)

Firstly, in my Eclipse environment, I am generating Java classes from my schema files. This functionality contains 4 XSDs. These are two of them:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:include schemaLocation="statisticsTypes.xsd" />
<xs:element name="data" type="Data" />  
</xs:schema>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:include schemaLocation="statisticsTypes.xsd" />
<xs:element name="dataList" type="DataList" />
</xs:schema>
```

The statisticsTypes.xsd looks like following (only partial code):

```
    .....
    <xs:complexType name="Data">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="abcType" type="ABCType" />
        <xs:element name="typeID" type="xs:long" />
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="DataList">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="data" type="Data" minOccurs="0"
            maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
.....
```

Any idea, how to solve this problem? It must be a problem in the XSD file, but still don't find the part to change.

Best

**Update 1**

The generated classes Data and DataList do not have a @xmlrootelement.

**Update 2**

ALthough I could "solve" parts of the problem by integrating bindings and allowing vendor extensions, for some REST operations, I am receiving the following error message:

"MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class ..., genericType=class ..."

How can I may be adapt the XSDs to fix this problem?

Comment: Any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: All suggestions I had found during my online search didn't solve the problem...